# Nginx/uwsgi request buffer or queue

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Our web servers run a Python app behind nginx + uwsgi.

Sometimes we have short spikes (2-5x avg no requests) for a second resulting in some requests getting a 502 if there are no workers available to handle them.

Is there a way for nginx or uwsgi to queue these requests up and serve them when workers become available?

It's better with a short increase in response time rather than getting an error ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no way for nginx to do that**. Directive **queue** is available as part of Nginx **commercial subscription only**. https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#queue

A good decision is run several (2 or more) uwsgi backends with nginx **uwsgi_next_upstream** directive https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_next_upstream.

Also you can try `error_page 502 =307 http://backup.example.com/;`